# Cannot print the dictionary value when used in print formatting in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
dict = {}
dict['a'] = 1
```

for my above dictionary:

```
print(dict['a'])
```

works fine, but

```
print(f'a is: {dict['a']}')
```

this print statement gives syntax error. I am not sure why?

Comment: check your quotes?

Answer (score 4):

You're using single quotes in a single quoted string. Replace outermost quotes for double quotes and it should work

```
print(f"a is: {dict['a']}")
```

Comment: just note that the inverse solution  (`f'a is: {dict["a"]}'`) works just as well...

Answer (score 2):

Use double quote:

```
print(f"a is: {dict['a']}")
```

**@Nicolas Martinez answered it 4 seconds earlier, accept his answer instead**